# Docker set user password non-interactively

Tags: docker, authentication, dockerfile, passwd

I would like to set my user `vault`'s password in the Dockerfile and I have tried

```
RUN echo -e "pass\npass" | passwd "${USER}"
```

but get

```
Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: Sorry, passwords do not match
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
The command '/bin/sh -c echo -e "pass\npass" | passwd "${USER}"' returned a non-zero code: 10
```

and am wondering if there's a better way to do this, instead?

Comment: You shouldn't usually need a user password at all; you can't "log in" to a container in any meaningful way, and there's nothing you can usually do in a container that needs a password.  (If you need a root shell for debugging purposes, you can `docker run -u root` or `docker exec -u root`.)  What's leading you to try to set this?

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to be able to sudo from the user account inside the container and it asks for the user password when I want to sudo (I've added the user to the sudo group with `RUN adduser "${USER}" sudo`)

Comment: @DavidMaze I want to ssh into the container, and that requires a password (don't want a passwordless ssh)

Comment: @DavidMaze you're a genius!! ```docker exec -u root``` is all we need!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using `passwd`, there is another utility for the: `chpasswd`. I've resolved this by using the following command in my Dockerfile (after creation of the user):

```
RUN echo "${USER}:pass" | chpasswd
```

works like a charm!

Comment: getting `
chpasswd: (user ${UNAME}) pam_chauthtok() failed, error:
Authentication token manipulation error
chpasswd: (line 1, user ${UNAME}) password not changed
`

Comment: getting the above error too

Comment: @WalksB Is this because of [this comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5704#issuecomment-1362575038)?

Comment: @Gulzar In my case "${USER}:pass" expansion was not working I used "root:pass", meaning a hardcoded username and it worked.

Comment: Just know that `docker history` for the image will reveal that password in clear text even without access to the Dockerfile.